# Git push origin works, but server is not updating

Tags: git, push, git-push, multiple-repositories

I have a git with two remotes, let's say primary and secondary. My workflow usually goes like this:

For remote primary:

1. Push changes to remote primary from directory A,
2. Pull changes from remote secondary to directory A (if any),
3. Change necessary files,
4. Push changes to both remote primary and secondary.

And just a normal git pull - change - git push in the secondary remote.

Recently when I do git push on remote primary I always got an error that says: `Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge`. Even so, the git push went on, and if I check with git status it says everything is up to date. So I thought it is good.

However when I look at the website, it seems like it is not using the latest code I pushed. I have tried to change and push the files related to the error; checkout the commit related to the error and push changes on it; but no result so far.

Any thought on how should I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: You are committing these files, correct?

Comment: I recommand you to fetch from the conflicting remote first, and find out why you get a conflict. Probably, you made a local history modification on some commits which were already pushed to the remote repository.

Comment: You should push to a bare repo.

Comment: @BlackVegetable yes I am committing the files.

Comment: @Vincent, If I recall correctly, you are right about history modification. Anyway, I was trying to do your suggestion when my boss ordered to update the site. So I updated it via SFTP and it messed up the git so bad. I am thinking of re-init the git in the remote. Think it should be solving the problem? P.s. I'm not so good in git and stuffs.

Comment: Are you using the command line or a gui tool?

Comment: Do you have the [exact] command sequence so that we can see what may have happended. Indicate any redacted/altered for security parts. My guess is a confusion (easy to make;-) between remote (tracking) and local branches, and also the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

You can force a push by using the parameter `-f`.

For instance, `git push -f`